# Geometry Node issue - Distribute Points on Faces not working?

Tags: geometry-nodes

so I'm trying to follow this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBJ-HuBL6gw&list=PLgO2ChD7acqHzccBuhAGw8dTPLnR1E3QB&index=4

Which is 2 years old and outdated, so is using Point Instance Node, which doesn't exist anymore.  It has been brought up in comments and updated, but not explained as well.

Comments updated that to get the ico sphere to the wireframe faces to work, we have to use Distribute points on faces into an instance on points node into the join geometry node at the end, then add the ico sphere and connect it to the instance slot of instance on points node.  ChatGPT says this same thing.

In 4.0 this does not work.  Is this a bug or did they change it again and it's not being explained anywhere?

I tried all sorts of combinations of this into every slot and the icosphere will not show up.  I see others in the comments having the same issue and people keep repeating these steps like it's supposed to help when it is not working.

Trying to ask here since the Devs don't like when people report it as a bug if there was some sort of work around implemented but not told or updated =/

Comment: Geometry Nodes have changed substantially since the alpha version of Blender 3.0 where the code for them was still being written so I'd suggest you try to find a more up to date tutorial to follow! Version 4 tutorials are now starting to appear, for instance [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsGl9GczcgBsDZ3jQPwP1p6evNI22wevP) series from Ryan King Art.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I was struggling trying to find updated videos.

I did however end up digging through enough comments buried that had the correct answer for anyone else on this.

Apparently it was as simple as taking the transform node from the original mesh, not the sphere, and plugging it into the points port on the instance on points, then plugging all the stuff with the new sphere into the instance port and finally worked.

Comment: Hello, Thai, welcome. If this is fixed, I think it would be fair to close this post.. unless you can clarify the **exact** problem you were having (The video is very long), and put in the solution as a self-answer. That would be OK for the archive. As it stands.. I'm not so sure. Do you agree?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm a noob.  it was around the 23:10 mark.  But I did find the workaround which is in my last comment.

I'm not seeing the option to close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to see if this is how I close this?

I found the workaround, there might be a couple other ways, but this was the thing that worked.

The issue in the video is at the 23:10m mark.

Apparently it was as simple as taking the transform node from the convex hull mesh, not the sphere like the guy and some others were explaining that it used to be pre 3.0, and plugging it into the points port on the instance on points, then plugging all the stuff with the new sphere into the instance port and finally worked.

This works 3.6 and 4.0